# I'm trying to make my loading screen cover the entire screen

Tags: css

I am trying to make my loading screen cover the entire page even when the scroll bar is on!

```
   .loading 
    {
       position:absolute;
       background: #CFECF9;
       filter:alpha(opacity=50);
       opacity:0.75;
       z-index:20;
       left:0;
       top:0;
       height:100%;
       width:100%;
       vertical-align:middle;
       text-align:center;
    }
```

Comment: Going to need more than just the css to know what's going on with your code

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3tsxznq0/

Comment: To put in simpler words: Something is not working, can you guess what I am doing and help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an element cover the whole screen make it fixed:

```
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* Apply other styles */
}
```

Absolute positioned elements will only cover their parent container.

Answer (score 0):

```
  .loading {
    position: fixed;  
    top: 0;  
    right: 0;  
    bottom: 0;  
    left: 0;  
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #CFECF9;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity:0.75;
    z-index:20;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
  }
```